# AS2 tab within a string

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I'm trying to create a tool that prompts the user for various values and then creates one string that is copied to the clipboard so that it can be pasted into excel. The question is, is there a character for tabbing across cells? I already know that \n will move to the next cell down, but I need to be able to go across as well.

Here is what I have so far(I'm just adding the julianDate var multiple times to test):

```
var julianDate:String;
var julianFunction:Object = new Object();
julianFunction.change = function(evt_obj:Object)
{
julianDate = evt_obj.target.text;
    var excelExport:String;
    excelExport = "";
    excelExport = julianDate + "\n" + julianDate + "\n\n\n";
    System.setClipboard(excelExport);
};
julian_txt.addEventListener("change",julianFunction);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this -

```
"\t"
```